# Intellij IDEA 14.1.2 throwing ClassNotFoundException upon running of a Java class

Tags: java, intellij-idea

My simplified project structure is as follows:

```
Project
   -src
       -Game.java
```

To run this, I created a Run Configuration with my main class as `Game` (no red squiggles) and the working directory `C:\...\Project`. When I run this configuration, however, it comes up with the exception of `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Game`. The full error message can be found at [this](http://pastebin.com/CRxTFM8D) PasteBin.

The `src` directory has been marked as my Source Directory, and my Project has a content root to `src`.

Any ideas on what this error may be caused by and how I can fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you put your project somewhere so I download it...

Comment: @igreen [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1cqo5OZqOKcfmMweTZucEJGcHhoSktxX0toeFh2ams3Rkl5eDB3U0g1WC1McGlNVFJSUlU&usp=sharing)

Comment: In my ENV it run without any problem. how you create the run configuration?